# Is there official way to create nodejs package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to create a package in nodejs with standard-structure folders and files.

Before I do it by `npm init`, I wonder if there is a official way to do it?

A command that creates a standard folders and files that every package need follow by design doc.